# Haskell PointFree

Tags: haskell

How can I convert my function test' that takes  l (list of elements) ,n (step) and returns list of  selected by step elements to PointFree function?

```
test' n l = test'' n l 0
test'' n [] c = []
test'' n (x:xs) 0 = x:(test'' n xs 1)
test'' n (x:xs) c 
     |n==c =x:(test'' n xs 1)
     |otherwise =test'' n xs (c+1)
```

Method2

```
test' m = map snd . filter (\(x,y) -> (mod x m) == 0) . zip [0..]
```

`test' 2 [1,2,3,4,5]`  Result [1,3,5]
`test' 2 "ASDFG`  Result "ADG"
P.S
Can't use any imports

Comment: Why would you need to?  Pointfree functions are fun, but rarely are they a better solution to your problem.  Also, this implementation is quite complicated compared to what you can do in Haskell.

Comment: just university task  to implement  test' function( I implement it with arguments but should be PointFree

Comment: @Spamu3 This implementation is going to be very difficult to make point free, I would recommend working on the implementation using more functions from `Prelude` first.  That will be much easier to make point free.

Comment: A hint, another way to solve this problem would be to take your list and first turn it into a list of lists, each with length `n`, then you can simply grab the first element from each of those.

Comment: I get rid of  list but still 'n' left

Comment: Where are you study if it isn't secret? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a point-free version

```
import Control.Category (>>>)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

skips =
  pred >>>                        -- \n -> n-1
  (`replicate` const Nothing) >>> -- \n -> [ const Nothing, ..., const Nothing ] -- length n -1
  (Just:) >>>                     -- \n -> [ Just, const Nothing, ... const Nothing ] -- length n
  cycle >>>                       -- \n -> [ Just, const Nothing, ... const Nothing, Just, const Nothing, ... ] -- infinite length
  zipWith ($) >>>                 -- \n [ a0, a1, .., aN, aNPlus1, ... ] -> [ Just a0, Nothing, ..., Just aN, Nothing, ... ]
  (catMaybes .)                   -- \n [ a0, a1, .., aN, aNPlus1, ... ] -> [a0, aN, a2N, ...]
```

As others have said, something like this is going to be easier to understand
with the pointful definition.

The only reason I used `>>>` (aka `flip (.)`) was so you could follow the documentation more easily.  An equivalent definition is:

```
skips = (catMaybes .) . zipWith ($) . cycle . (Just:) . (`replicate` const Nothing) . pred
```

Two point-free tricks it's good to highlight:

- `` (`replicate` const Nothing) `` is equivalent to `(flip replicate (const Nothing))` or `(\n -> replicate n (const Nothing))`
- `(catMaybes .) . f` is equivalent to `\n -> catMaybes . f n` or `\n xs -> catMaybes (f n xs)`

If you can't import `catMaybes`, you can replace it by its point-free definition `concatMap (maybe [] return)`, making an import-free definition:

```
skips = (concatMap (maybe [] return) .) . zipWith ($) . cycle . (Just:) . (`replicate` const Nothing) . pred
```

which can be simplified to

```
skips = (concat.) . zipWith ($) . cycle . (return:) . (`replicate` const []) . pred
```

Comment: sry but can't use any imports(

Comment: Let me know what seems "magical" or hard to understand and I'll flesh out my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of indices, then map `(l !!)` over that list.

```
mySlice l n = map (l !!) l [0,n..length l - 1]
```

This is going to be much easier to understand than any point-free version. (As an example, the above is processed by http://pointfree.io to

```
liftM2 (.) (map =<< (!!)) (flip (enumFromThenTo 0) . subtract 1 . length))
```

---

Update:

As pointed out by @rampion, using `!!` with a regular list will lead to poor performance, since it is not an O(1) operation. Instead, try this list comprehension which zips the list with a list of potential indices.

```
mySlice l n = [ x | (x,i) <- zip l (cycle [0..n-1]), i == 0]
```

Comment: Note that `(!!)` is going to be linear in the length of the input list, which will make `mySlice` quadratic.  Probably not important on most data, but worth noting.

Comment: No, good point. This is actually a pretty terrible simplification.